# Firebase Database: query denormalized data struggles

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Given the following structure, how do I go about retrieving a particular users notifications?

ie: `uid0001` shoud be able to retrieve a list: `[xxxxx01, xxxxx02]`:

```
notifications
  uid01
    xxxxx01
  uid02
    xxxxx02
  uid03
    xxxxx03
  uid04
    xxxxx04
users
  uid0001
    notifications
      uid01
      uid02
```

Unfortunately, this monstrosity is extremely inefficient:

```
firebase.database().ref(`users/${user.userId}/notifications`).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((data) => {
    firebase.database().ref(`notifications/${data.key}`).once('value').then((snap) => {
      this.list.unshift(localUpdates)
    })
  })
})
```

Possibly something along the lines of (warning, pseudo code coming):

```
firebase.database().ref('notifications').on('child_added').equalTo('whatever the childs key is here').then((snapshot) => {

})
```

As always any direction, cheers jeers and rotten fruit is welcomed, so thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of soltions; here's two (forgive the pseudo code as I dont know your platform)

*The ok way*

Using your existing structure, capture the child nodes in /users/uid0001/notifications then iterate over those children, reading the children in the notifications node one at a time.

*The better way*

```
notifications
  -yisijaoijsijdasd //generated by push() or childByAutoId()
    for_user: "uid01"
    notification: "Check this out"
    timestamp: "20170421"
    user_time: "uid01_20170421" //concatenated allows queries by > 1 item
  -Y9s90kas9dkka9s
    for_user: uid01
    notification: "Yipee"
    timestamp: "20170426"
    user_time: "uid01_20170426"

users
  uid0001
```

Then query the notifications node for:

all notifications for uid01

```
notificationsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "for_user").equalTo("uid01")
```

all notifications for uid01 for the last 4 days

```
notificationsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "user_time")
                .startingAt("uid01_20170422")
                .endingAt("uid01_20170426")
```

you could expand on this - for example if you wanted to keep track of the notifications that have not been read, you could add

```
notifications
  -yisijaoijsijdasd //generated by push() or childByAutoId()
    for_user: "uid01"
    notification: "Check this out"
    timestamp: "20170421"
    user_time: "uid01_20170421"
    was_read: false
    user_read: "uid01_false"
```

and query for

```
notificationsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "user_read").equalTo("uid01_false")
```

Comment: This something I have been contemplating.  The `for_user` would need to be an array.  Could the `queryOrdered` still work like an any?  For Instance: ```queryOdered(byChild: "for_user").contains("uid01")```

Comment: @studiobrain No. Please do NOT use or store array's in Firebase! See [Array's Are Evil](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html). With the structure I propose, there's no reason to use arrays anyway. There is no 'contains' in Firebase which is why I included options in my solution so you could query for data in a variety of ways.

Comment: Agreed, that wasnt meant as a literal to array as much as just a list.  The above will work great, I just to go one level deeper to get the associated notification based on user...  Thanks!

Comment: @studiobrain I don't think you need to go one level deeper - the structure in my solution is denormalized, highly queryable and easily updatable. Just query the notifications node for 'uid01' to get all the notifications for that user... or uid01_20170427 for that users notifications for today. Etc.

Comment: word!  implementing now.